# How do i split ajax return values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to split the ajax returned values using jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
var url = "/StudentProgress/GetStudProgDet/";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { currentAcadYr: iAcademicYearText, currentSem: iSemesterText },
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {

            var result = $(data).text().split(':');
            var ProgAcadYearCode = result[0].ProgAcadYearCode;
            var productSize = result[1];

           // alert(data.ProgAcadYearCode);
            //$("#ToProgressAcademicYearId option").filter(function () {
            //    return this.text == testsem;
            //}).attr('selected', true);
        },
        error: function (reponse) {
            alert("error : " + reponse);
        }
    });
```

I got a result like this:

```
data = {
  success: true,
  progAcadYearCode: 20172018, 
  progAcadYearId: 17, 
  progressSemId: 47, 
  progressSemNo: 2
}
```

How do I extract the desired values from the JSON using jQuery?

Comment: Well, that's JSON - what are you trying to accomplish? It's an object you can directly work with.

Comment: actually @TiesonT., that's not JSON, it's a plain ol' javascript object, which has already been parsed from a JSON response

Comment: @JaromandaX I wanted to say "poe-tay-toe, pah-tah-toe," but I would be wrong. Still not sure what the OP is trying to do, though.

Comment: well ... To-mah-toe :p

Comment: console.log(data.success);
   console.log(data.progAcadYearCode); this  is th solution..got it.. thanks  u all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on `data` what you shown,you have to directly fetch it's properties like below:-

```
success: function (data) {
   console.log(data.success);
   console.log(data.progAcadYearCode); //and so on
},
```